# How do I pass a Mongod field selector to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, parameters

I have a very basic question that I can't seem to find the answer to, I hope you can help out!

I am trying to create a JavaScript function that return a specific result from my mongodb collection. The function has two arguments, one is a selector within the collection and the other one the field that needs to be retrieved.

```
returnOrganisation = function (id, property){
    return Published.findOne({_id:id}).property
}
```

The id parameter does work

```
 return Published.findOne({_id:id}).name;
```

But when trying to add the property parameter I get the following error:

> update failed: MongoError: '$set' is empty. You must specify a field
>   like so: {$mod: {: ...}}

**So my question is: How do I pass the property to return (for instance, the .name of the object in my collection) to the function?**

I'm sure this should not be too hard to do, but can't seem to get this to work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **[bracket notation syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)** to access the property like this:

```
returnOrganisation = function (id, property_name){
    var result = Published.findOne({_id:id});
    return result[property_name];
}
```